# Undefined variables sent from AJAX to PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this form that it should send values into AJAX then to PHP and get some queries executed and finally, we should get another response from ajax.

My HTML form is the following where we add information about dentist project for a a patient:

```
        <form>
    <div class="box-body" id="toggleDiv">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label style="float:left">Starting date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date_now" name="date_now"/>
            <label style="float:left">Project Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project_desc" name="project_desc"/>
            <label style="float:left">Project Cost</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project_cost" name="project_cost"/>
            <label style="float:left">Payment Type</label>
            <select class="form-control select2" id="pay_type" name="pay_type">
                <option value="0">Choose</option>
                <option value="cash">Cash</option>
                <option value="installment">Instalment</option>
            </select>
            <label style="float:left;">First Payment (In case of installment)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_pay" name="first_pay"/>
            <label style="float:left">Date of Payment</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date_pay" name="date_pay"/>
          </div><!-- /.form-group -->

        </div><!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label style="float:left">Inssurance Type (Gov, Social, ...)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inssurance" name="inssurance"/>
            <label style="float:left">Prescription</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prescription" name="prescription"/>

              <div class="box box-danger">

                <div class="box-body">
                  <!-- Date dd/mm/yyyy -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                      </div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ext" name="ext" placeholder="ext"/>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="do" name="do" placeholder="do"/>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endo" name="endo" placeholder="endo"/>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fm" name="fm" placeholder="fm"/>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="crown" name="crown" placeholder="crown"/>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rmvbl" name="rmvbl" placeholder="rmvbl"/>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="paro" name="paro" placeholder="paro"/>
                    </div><!-- /.input group -->
                </div><!-- /.form group -->
            </div>
          </div>
          </div><!-- /.form-group -->
          <div class="form-group">

          </div><!-- /.form-group -->
        </div><!-- /.col -->

      </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div><!-- /.box-body -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

      <div class="box box-danger">
        <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="box-title">Upper Jaw</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
          <!-- IP mask -->
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Upper Right Teeth</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i><img src="../images/molar.png" style="width:15px; height:15px"/>Upper Right</i>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="one" name="one" placeholder="3rd Molar"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="two" name="two" placeholder="2nd Molar"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="three" name="three" placeholder="1st Molar"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="four" name="four" placeholder="2nd Bicuspid"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="five" name="five" placeholder="1st Bicuspid"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="six" name="six" placeholder="cuspid"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="seven" name="seven" placeholder="lateral"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eight" name="eight" placeholder="central"/>
            </div><!-- /.input group -->
          </div><!-- /.form group -->
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Upper Left Teeth</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nine" name="nine" placeholder="3rd Molar"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ten" name="ten" placeholder="2nd Molar"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eleven" name="eleven" placeholder="1st Molar"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="twelve" name="twelve" placeholder="2nd Bicuspid"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="thirteen" name="thirteen" placeholder="1st Bicuspid"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fourteen" name="fourteen" placeholder="cuspid"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fifteen" name="fifteen" placeholder="lateral"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sixteen" name="sixteen" placeholder="central"/>
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i><img src="../images/molar.png" style="width:15px; height:15px"/>Upper Left</i>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.input group -->
          </div><!-- /.form group -->
        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
      </div><!-- /.box -->

    </div><!-- /.col (left) -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="box-title">Lower Jaw</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
          <!-- IP mask -->
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Lower Right Teeth</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i><img src="../images/molar.png" style="width:15px; height:15px"/>Lower Right</i>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lone" name="lone" placeholder="3rd Molar"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ltwo" name="ltwo" placeholder="2nd Molar"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lthree" name="lthree" placeholder="1st Molar"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lfour" name="lfour" placeholder="2nd Bicuspid"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lfive" name="lfive" placeholder="1st Bicuspid"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lsix" name="lsix" placeholder="cuspid"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lseven" name="lseven" placeholder="lateral"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="leight" name="leight" placeholder="central"/>
            </div><!-- /.input group -->
          </div><!-- /.form group -->
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Lower Left Teeth</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lnine" name="lnine" placeholder="3rd Molar"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lten" name="lten" placeholder="2nd Molar"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="leleven" name="leleven" placeholder="1st Molar"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ltwelve" name="ltwelve" placeholder="2nd Bicuspid"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lthirteen" name="lthirteen" placeholder="1st Bicuspid"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lfourteen" name="lfourteen" placeholder="cuspid"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lfifteen" name="lfifteen" placeholder="lateral"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lsixteen" name="lsixteen" placeholder="central"/>
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i><img src="../images/molar.png" style="width:15px; height:15px"/>Lower Left</i>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.input group -->
          </div><!-- /.form group -->
        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
      </div><!-- /.box -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="add_project">Add</button>

      <!-- iCheck -->

    </div><!-- /.col (right) -->
  </div><!-- /.row -->
```

And here my AJAX script:

```
$("#add_project").click(function()
{
    //Patient ID
    var pid = '<?php echo $patient_id ?>';
    console.log(pid);
    //variables
    var pay_type = $("#pay_type").val();
    console.log(pay_type);
    var project_cost = $("#project_cost").val();
    var project_desc = $("#project_desc").val();
    var date_now = $("#date_now").val();
    var first_pay = $("#first_pay").val();
    var date_pay = $("#date_pay").val();
    console.log(date_pay);
    var inssurance = $("#inssurance").val();
    var prescription = $("#prescription").val();

    var ext = $("#ext").val();
    var doo = $("#do").val();
    console.log(doo);
    var endo = $("#endo").val();
    var fm = $("#fm").val();
    var crown = $("#crown").val();
    var rmvbl = $("#rmvbl").val();
    var paro = $("#paro").val();

    //teeth
    var ur_t_molar = $("#one").val();
    var ur_s_molar = $("#two").val();
    var ur_f_molar = $("#three").val();
    var ur_s_bicuspid = $("#four").val();
    var ur_f_bicuspid = $("#five").val();
    var ur_bicuspid = $("#six").val();
    var ur_lateral = $("#seven").val();
    var ur_central = $("#eight").val();

    var ul_t_molar = $("#nine").val();
    var ul_s_molar = $("#ten").val();
    var ul_f_molar = $("#eleven").val();
    var ul_s_bicuspid = $("#twelve").val();
    var ul_f_bicuspid = $("#thirteen").val();
    var ul_bicuspid = $("#fourteen").val();
    var ul_lateral = $("#fifteen").val();
    var ul_central = $("#sixteen").val();
    console.log(ul_central);
    var lr_t_molar = $("#lone").val();
    var lr_s_molar = $("#ltwo").val();
    var lr_f_molar = $("#lthree").val();
    var lr_s_bicuspid = $("#lfour").val();
    var lr_f_bicuspid = $("#lfive").val();
    var lr_bicuspid = $("#lsix").val();
    var lr_lateral = $("#lseven").val();
    var lr_central = $("#leight").val();

    var ll_t_molar = $("#lnine").val();
    var ll_s_molar = $("#lten").val();
    var ll_f_molar = $("#leleven").val();
    var ll_s_bicuspid = $("#ltwelve").val();
    var ll_f_bicuspid = $("#lthirteen").val();
    var ll_bicuspid = $("#lfourteen").val();
    var ll_lateral = $("#lfifteen").val();
    var ll_central = $("#lsixteen").val();

    //Conditions before sending data through ajax into php code
    if(project_cost == "" || pay_type == 0 || project_desc == "" || date_pay == "")
    {
        alert("Please add a project description, with cost and type of payment!");
        $("#project_cost").css('border-color', 'red');
        $("#pay_type").css('border-color', 'red');
        $("#date_pay").css('border-color', 'red');
        $("#project_desc").css('border-color', 'red');
    }
    if(project_cost != "" && pay_type != 0 && project_desc != "" && date_pay != "")
    {
        //Ajax script starts here
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: 'add_project.php',
            type: 'post',
            date: {patient_id: pid, payment_type: pay_type, project_c: project_cost, proj_d: project_desc, 
                dn: date_now, fp: first_pay, date_p: date_pay, 
                ins: inssurance, presc: prescription, e: ext, 
                d: doo, en: endo, f: fm, 
                c: crown, r: rmvbl, p: paro,
                one: ur_t_molar, two: ur_s_molar, three: ur_f_molar, 
                four: ur_s_bicuspid, five: ur_f_bicuspid, six: ur_bicuspid, 
                seven: ur_lateral, eight: ur_central, nine: ul_t_molar, ten: ul_s_molar,
                eleven: ul_f_molar, twelve: ul_s_bicuspid, thirteen: ul_f_bicuspid,
                fourteen: ul_bicuspid, fifteen: ul_lateral, sixteen: ul_central,
                lone: lr_t_molar, ltwo: lr_s_molar, lthree: lr_f_molar, 
                lfour: lr_s_bicuspid, lfive: lr_f_bicuspid, lsix: lr_bicuspid, 
                lseven: lr_lateral, leight: lr_central, lnine: ll_t_molar, lten: ll_s_molar,
                leleven: ll_f_molar, ltwelve: ll_s_bicuspid, lthirteen: ll_f_bicuspid,
                lfourteen: ll_bicuspid, lfifteen: ll_lateral, lsixteen: ll_central},
            dataType: 'text',

            success:function(res)
            {
                if(res=="added")
                {
                    alert("information added");
                }
            },
            error:function(res)
            {
                if(res!="added"){
                    alert("Their is some errors in data, please try again!");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Now when I click on the add button, I can see some of information using console (like pid, ext, ...), but when php code is executed, I get error for each variable saying:

> Notice: Undefined index: `my_variable` in...

Here is my console output:

[image]

And here is my php code where I get each value using `$_POST['']`:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

require_once('../include/global.php');
//session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$id_logged = $_SESSION['login_id'];
//Getting Patient ID
$patient_id = $_POST['patient_id'];

//Getting other variables
$payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
$project_c = $_POST['project_c'];
$proj_d = $_POST['proj_d'];
$dn = $_POST['dn'];
$fp = $_POST['fp'];
$date_p = $_POST['date_p'];
$ins = $_POST['ins'];
$presc = $_POST['presc'];
$e = $_POST['e'];
$d = $_POST['p'];
$en = $_POST['en'];
$f = $_POST['f'];
$c = $_POST['c'];
$r = $_POST['r'];
$p = $_POST['p'];
$one = $_POST['one'];
$two = $_POST['two'];
$three =$_POST['three'];
$four = $_POST['four'];
$five =$_POST['five'];
$six = $_POST['six'];
$seven = $_POST['seven'];
$eight =$_POST['eight'];
$nine =$_POST['nine'];
$ten =$_POST['ten'];
$eleven = $_POST['eleven'];
$twelve = $_POST['twelve'];
$thirteen = $_POST['thirteen'];
$fourteen = $_POST['fourteen'];
$fifteen = $_POST['fifteen'];
$sixteen =$_POST['sixteen'];
$lone = $_POST['lone'];
$ltwo = $_POST['ltwo'];
$lthree =$_POST['lthree'];
$lfour = $_POST['lfour'];
$lfive =$_POST['lfive'];
$lsix = $_POST['lsix'];
$lseven = $_POST['lseven'];
$leight =$_POST['leight'];
$lnine =$_POST['lnine'];
$lten =$_POST['lten'];
$leleven = $_POST['leleven'];
$ltwelve = $_POST['ltwelve'];
$lthirteen = $_POST['lthirteen'];
$lfourteen = $_POST['lfourteen'];
$lfifteen = $_POST['lfifteen'];
$lsixteen =$_POST['lsixteen'];

if($payment_type == "cash")
{
    try
    {
        //Insert into patient Info
        $sqlInfo = "INSERT INTO patient_info(id_logged, patient_id, insurrance_type, project, project_cost,
                    payment_type, prescription, date_now, time_now, ext, do, endo, fm, crown, rmvbl, paro)
                    VALUES(:id_logged, :patient_id, :ins, :proj_d, :project_c, :payment_type, :presc,
                        :date_p, now(), :e, :d, :en, :f, :c, :r, :p)";
        $sqlInfoStmt = $conn->prepare($sqlInfo);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":id_logged", $id_logged);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":patient_id", $patient_id);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":ins", $ins);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":proj_d", $proj_d);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":project_c", $project_c);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":payment_type", $payment_type);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":presc", $presc);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":date_p", $date_p);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":e", $e);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":d", $d);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":en", $en);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":f", $f);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":c", $c);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":r", $e);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":p", $p);

        $sqlInfoStmt->execute();

        //Insert into teeth table
        $sqlTeeth = "INSERT INTO teeth (id_logged, patient_id, one, two, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, eleven, twelve, thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, sixteen, seventeen, eightteen, nineteen, twenty, twone, twtwo, twthree, twfour, twfive, twsix, twseven, tweight, twnine, thirty, thone, thtwo, date_now) VALUES (:id_logged, :patient_id, :one, :two, :three, :four, :five, :six, :seven, :eight, :nine, :ten, :eleven, :twelve, :thirteen,
            :fourteen, :fifteen, :sixteen, :lone, :ltwo, :lthree, :lfour, :lfive, :lsix, :lseven, :leight, :lnine, :lten, :leleven, :ltwelve, :lthirteen,
            :lfourteen, :lfifteen, :lsixteen)";
        $sqlTeethStmt = $conn->prepare($sqlTeeth);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":id_logged", $id_logged);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":patient_id", $patient_id);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":one", $one);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":two", $two);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":three", $three);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":four", $four);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":five", $five);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":six", $six);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":seven", $seven);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":eight", $eight);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":nine", $nine);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":ten", $ten);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":eleven", $eleven);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":twelve", $twelve);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":thirteen", $thirteen);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":fourteen", $fourteen);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":fifteen", $fifteen);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":sixteen", $sixteen);

        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lone", $lone);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":ltwo", $ltwo);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lthree", $lthree);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lfour", $lfour);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lfive", $lfive);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lsix", $lsix);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lseven", $lseven);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":leight", $leight);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lnine", $lnine);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lten", $lten);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":leleven", $leleven);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":ltwelve", $ltwelve);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lthirteen", $lthirteen);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lfourteen", $lfourteen);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lfifteen", $lfifteen);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lsixteen", $lsixteen);

        $sqlTeethStmt->execute();

        echo "added";
    }
    catch(PDOException $msg)
    {
        $msg->getMessage();
        echo "not added";
    }
}

if($payment_type == "debt")
{

}
?>
```

**Seeing values in the console, means that the problem is only at the server side ?**. I hope that I can get some help.

Comment: where do you see this error? on what page?

Comment: I see the error undefined variables at my php file at the devtool of google chrome

Comment: Precisely at the network XHR

Comment: ohh man, why are u not using formSeriliaze data like `$( form ).serialize()`

Comment: This is pretty unreadable. Can you reproduce the problem with only 1 or 2 variables? If yes, please post that code.

Comment: i think you have a post variable that you don't pass to the php file a simple fix will be to remove the debugging code because this is a notice

Comment: Your ajax reads `date: {var: value, ...}` shouldn't that be `data:{...}` :P

Comment: yep that is it. Thanks now fixed