# Unknown error in php code

Tags: php, ajax

Following [this question asked and fixed earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887253/undefined-variables-sent-from-ajax-to-php-server?noredirect=1#comment59437976_35887253), I continued with the second part of the PHP code where I have `if($payment_type == "installment")`.

And in this part I need to get the last inserted id into table `patient_info` and added into `debt` table as `info_id`. The debt table take the role of saving the installment info about each `project` set as `installment`.

The code now is:

```
if($payment_type == "installment")
{
    try
    {
        //Insert into patient Info
        $sqlInfo = "INSERT INTO patient_info(id_logged, patient_id, insurrance_type, project, project_cost,
                    payment_type, prescription, date_now, time_now, ext, do, endo, fm, crown, rmvbl, paro)
                    VALUES(:id_logged, :patient_id, :ins, :proj_d, :project_c, :payment_type, :presc,
                        :date_p, now(), :e, :d, :en, :f, :c, :r, :p)";
        $sqlInfoStmt = $conn->prepare($sqlInfo);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":id_logged", $id_logged);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":patient_id", $patient_id);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":ins", $ins);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":proj_d", $proj_d);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":project_c", $project_c);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":payment_type", $payment_type);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":presc", $presc);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":date_p", $date_p);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":e", $e);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":d", $d);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":en", $en);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":f", $f);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":c", $c);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":r", $r);
        $sqlInfoStmt->bindValue(":p", $p);

        $sqlInfoStmt->execute();


        //get the project info id
        $lastId = $conn->lastInsertId();
        //Insert into teeth table
        $sqlTeeth = "INSERT INTO teeth (id_logged, patient_id, one, two, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, eleven, twelve, thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, sixteen, seventeen, eightteen, nineteen, twenty, twone, twtwo, twthree, twfour, twfive, twsix, twseven, tweight, twnine, thirty, thone, thtwo, date_now) VALUES (:id_logged, :patient_id, :one, :two, :three, :four, :five, :six, :seven, :eight, :nine, :ten, :eleven, :twelve, :thirteen,
            :fourteen, :fifteen, :sixteen, :lone, :ltwo, :lthree, :lfour, :lfive, :lsix, :lseven, :leight, :lnine, :lten, :leleven, :ltwelve, :lthirteen,
            :lfourteen, :lfifteen, :lsixteen)";
        $sqlTeethStmt = $conn->prepare($sqlTeeth);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":id_logged", $id_logged);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":patient_id", $patient_id);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":one", $one);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":two", $two);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":three", $three);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":four", $four);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":five", $five);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":six", $six);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":seven", $seven);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":eight", $eight);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":nine", $nine);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":ten", $ten);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":eleven", $eleven);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":twelve", $twelve);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":thirteen", $thirteen);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":fourteen", $fourteen);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":fifteen", $fifteen);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":sixteen", $sixteen);

        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lone", $lone);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":ltwo", $ltwo);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lthree", $lthree);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lfour", $lfour);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lfive", $lfive);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lsix", $lsix);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lseven", $lseven);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":leight", $leight);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lnine", $lnine);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lten", $lten);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":leleven", $leleven);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":ltwelve", $ltwelve);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lthirteen", $lthirteen);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lfourteen", $lfourteen);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lfifteen", $lfifteen);
        $sqlTeethStmt->bindValue(":lsixteen", $lsixteen);

        $sqlTeethStmt->execute();

        try
        {
        //Add to debt table
            $sqlDebt = "INSERT INTO debt(info_id, id_logged, patient_id, payment, date_now, time_now)
                        VALUES(:info_id, :id_logged, :patient_id, :payment, :date_now, now())";
            $sqlDebtStmt = $conn->prepare($sqlDebt);
            $sqlDebtStmt->bindValue(":info_id", $lastId);
            $sqlDebtStmt->bindValue(":id_logged", $id_logged);
            $sqlDebtStmt->bindValue(":patient_id", $patient_id);
            $sqlDebtStmt->bindValue(":payment", $fp);
            $sqlDebtStmt->bindValue(":date_now", $date_p);
            $sqlDebtStmt->execute();
            echo "added";
        }
        catch(PDOException $msg)
        {
            echo $msg->getMessage();
            //echo "not added";
        }

    }
    catch(PDOException $msg)
    {
        echo $msg->getMessage();
        //echo "not added";
    }
}
```

I didn't change anything in AJAX script, and when I choose the type `installment`, data are added properly `to patient_info` and `teeth`, but not added into `debt table`. I can't see any log error in XHR or console.

**FORM**

```
<form>
            <div class="box-body" id="toggleDiv">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="float:left">Starting date</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date_now" name="date_now"/>
                    <label style="float:left">Project Description</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project_desc" name="project_desc"/>
                    <label style="float:left">Project Cost</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project_cost" name="project_cost"/>
                    <label style="float:left">Payment Type</label>
                    <select class="form-control select2" id="pay_type" name="pay_type">
                        <option value="0">Choose</option>
                        <option value="cash">Cash</option>
                        <option value="installment">Installment</option>
                    </select>
                    <label style="float:left;">First Payment (In case of installment)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_pay" name="first_pay"/>
                    <label style="float:left">Date of Payment</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date_pay" name="date_pay"/>
                  </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                </div><!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="float:left">Inssurance Type (Gov, Social, ...)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inssurance" name="inssurance"/>
                    <label style="float:left">Prescription</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prescription" name="prescription"/>

                      <div class="box box-danger">

                        <div class="box-body">
                          <!-- Date dd/mm/yyyy -->
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                              <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                              </div>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ext" name="ext" placeholder="ext"/>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="do" name="do" placeholder="do"/>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endo" name="endo" placeholder="endo"/>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fm" name="fm" placeholder="fm"/>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="crown" name="crown" placeholder="crown"/>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rmvbl" name="rmvbl" placeholder="rmvbl"/>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="paro" name="paro" placeholder="paro"/>
                            </div><!-- /.input group -->
                        </div><!-- /.form group -->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                  <div class="form-group">

                  </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                </div><!-- /.col -->

              </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.box-body -->

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">

              <div class="box box-danger">
                <div class="box-header">
                  <h3 class="box-title">Upper Jaw</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                  <!-- IP mask -->
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Upper Right Teeth</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i><img src="../images/molar.png" style="width:15px; height:15px"/>Upper Right</i>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="one" name="one" placeholder="3rd Molar"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="two" name="two" placeholder="2nd Molar"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="three" name="three" placeholder="1st Molar"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="four" name="four" placeholder="2nd Bicuspid"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="five" name="five" placeholder="1st Bicuspid"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="six" name="six" placeholder="cuspid"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="seven" name="seven" placeholder="lateral"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eight" name="eight" placeholder="central"/>
                    </div><!-- /.input group -->
                  </div><!-- /.form group -->
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Upper Left Teeth</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nine" name="nine" placeholder="3rd Molar"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ten" name="ten" placeholder="2nd Molar"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eleven" name="eleven" placeholder="1st Molar"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="twelve" name="twelve" placeholder="2nd Bicuspid"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="thirteen" name="thirteen" placeholder="1st Bicuspid"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fourteen" name="fourteen" placeholder="cuspid"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fifteen" name="fifteen" placeholder="lateral"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sixteen" name="sixteen" placeholder="central"/>
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i><img src="../images/molar.png" style="width:15px; height:15px"/>Upper Left</i>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.input group -->
                  </div><!-- /.form group -->
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
              </div><!-- /.box -->

            </div><!-- /.col (left) -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header">
                  <h3 class="box-title">Lower Jaw</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                  <!-- IP mask -->
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Lower Right Teeth</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i><img src="../images/molar.png" style="width:15px; height:15px"/>Lower Right</i>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lone" name="lone" placeholder="3rd Molar"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ltwo" name="ltwo" placeholder="2nd Molar"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lthree" name="lthree" placeholder="1st Molar"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lfour" name="lfour" placeholder="2nd Bicuspid"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lfive" name="lfive" placeholder="1st Bicuspid"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lsix" name="lsix" placeholder="cuspid"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lseven" name="lseven" placeholder="lateral"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="leight" name="leight" placeholder="central"/>
                    </div><!-- /.input group -->
                  </div><!-- /.form group -->
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Lower Left Teeth</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lnine" name="lnine" placeholder="3rd Molar"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lten" name="lten" placeholder="2nd Molar"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="leleven" name="leleven" placeholder="1st Molar"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ltwelve" name="ltwelve" placeholder="2nd Bicuspid"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lthirteen" name="lthirteen" placeholder="1st Bicuspid"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lfourteen" name="lfourteen" placeholder="cuspid"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lfifteen" name="lfifteen" placeholder="lateral"/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lsixteen" name="lsixteen" placeholder="central"/>
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i><img src="../images/molar.png" style="width:15px; height:15px"/>Lower Left</i>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.input group -->
                  </div><!-- /.form group -->
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
              </div><!-- /.box -->
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="add_project">Add</button>

              <!-- iCheck -->

            </div><!-- /.col (right) -->
          </div><!-- /.row -->
      </form>
```

Comment: Can we see the form? How are you setting `$payment_type`?

Comment: You're not checking for errors in your execute; try checking the return value, and looking to see if there's anything in `$sqlDebtStmt->errorInfo()`

Comment: you can see the form by clicking on the link provided at the top of this question. If I added the form here I think I will get something like duplicated post

Comment: no. post your form in the question. and what are you afraid of? if it's a duplicate, then it's a duplicate.

Comment: Ok I will post it wait a second

Comment: if there are any errors, use both error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and error checking on PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php should there be any and if you're not already checking for possible errors.

Comment: I am using `error_reporting` and when I hit F5 in the devtool network, and set some info and click on the button, nothing is shown at XHR

Comment: it's not the XHR you need to check for, it's for error exceptions in PDO as per the link I already gave you http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - Try `bindParam` instead of `bindValue` if it makes a difference. sometimes it does.

Comment: where I add the error info line ? I am new to pdo error handling

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is the way you are handling the data you have declared the value for variable $lastId

```
$lastId = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

And again you are using same variable for debt table it is obviously going to conflict the values to set and store for variable

Try to change the value in debt table to something else like renaming it to $lastIddebt

That should probably work.

Comment: You are defining the value for the variable $lastId as a function in previous code line.

Comment: Suppose i tell you to give x to mr a,  and to give y to mr a.... will it not be confusing for you to understand which one is for whom. so similarly in your debt table the mysql query you are telling the code to fetch value of variable $lastId but you are also declaring a value for $lastId in your previous query in same function. so it is getting confused which value it has to pass.